# VBA " __EVENTTARGET" and "__EVENTARGUMENT value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Folks..., I'm working on website that has 2 inputs called " __EVENTTARGET" and "__EVENTARGUMENT", is there a possibility to use VBA to find out what values are being passed to it ? because it also has a form named 'aspnetForm'. If I get those values I do know how to use vba to set the parameters for the form and then submit.

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value=""

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: *How* is VBA involved? (Was VBA ever even a valid ASP language target?)

Comment: This is a "internal" website from my work, so I do have to be logged to use it. I'm able to navegate through many pages. To do it I use vba and internet explorer automation.

Comment: You may try XHR instead of IE, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35854674/2165759). `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` uses IE cookies, so that might work after you login in IE.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911208/6241235)  as well

Comment: @user2864740 not VBA (it's running hosted on a desktop), but VBScript (pretty similar syntax) *was* the scripting language for ASP (Classic), pre-.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use the DOM Object, then it should be the value property:

```
set inputElement = ie.document.getElementsByName("name").item(0)
```

`inputElement.value` should be the target.

```
Sub a()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    With IE

      .Navigate2 "https://www.google.de"

       Do While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState <> 4
       Loop

       MsgBox .Document.getElementsByTagName("input").Item(0).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying using your code:  Set inputElement = IE.Document.getElementsByName("__EVENTTARGET").Item(0)
    MsgBox inputElement.Value

Comment: But, it gives me a "null" value:

Comment: weird? as per object spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement value should contain - does it maybe contain "null", can you try to set some random value and than msgbox?